# Trying to find a Unique Element in the ArrayList Implementation in Java. A getUnique Method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements MyList<T>{
    int num;        //number of things in the list
    T[] vals;       //to store the contents

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayList() {
        num = 0;
        vals = (T[]) new Object[3];
    }

public T getUnique(){
        T distinct = null;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
            distinct =  vals[i];
            for (int j = 0; j<vals.length; j++){
                if (vals[j] == vals[i]){
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 1){
                    return distinct;
                }
            }
        }
        if (distinct == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return distinct;
    }
```

I am trying to work on a get Unique Method. A method getUnique that takes no arguments and returns the first value in the list that appears only once. (For example, calling the method on the list [1,2,3,1,2,4] would return 3 since 1 and
2 both appear more than once.) If the list is empty or all its values appear more than once, the method throws a NoSuchElementException

Comment: If method getUnique takes no arguments how do you pass the list ? You initialize it inside the method ?

Comment: What's the precise question?

Comment: @mirzak Looks like it's a method of his list implementation. Ram: two questions: is this homework and what is your question?

Comment: Ah yea, you are right. I get it now.

Comment: @mirzak I initialize the list in the JUnit Test Case.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon So my question is, this getUnique method is returning the last value of the array instead of finding the unique one and returning it. For example, calling the method on the list [1,2,3,1,2,4] would return 3 since 1 and 2 both appear more than once. But it is returning 4.

Comment: So you want only the first unique one you came upon ?

Comment: @mirzak Yes. That is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some FIXME's to your code:

```
public T getUnique(){
    T distinct = null;
    int count = 0; // FIXME: move this initialization inside the i loop
    for (int i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
        distinct =  vals[i];
        for (int j = 0; j<vals.length; j++){
            if (vals[j] == vals[i]){ // FIXME: use .equals() not ==
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1){ // FIXME: move this check outside the j loop
                return distinct;
            }
        }
    }
    if (distinct == null){ //FIXME: no check needed, just throw it
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return distinct; //FIXME: no valid return can reach this point
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RamSharma  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Parker's advice will fix your code, but I wanted to provide a cleaner and faster solution to the problem of finding a unique element in a list. This algorithm runs in time `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.

```
public static <T> Optional<T> getUnique(List<T> ls) {
    // Create a map whose keys are elements of the list and whose values are
    // lists of their occurences. E.g. [1,2,3,1,2,4] becomes {1->[1, 1],
    // 2->[2, 2], 3->[3], 4->[4]}. Then elements.get(x).size() tells us how
    // many times x occured in ls.
    Map<T, List<T>> elements = ls.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x));
    // Find the first element that occurs exactly one time in ls.
    return ls.stream().filter(x -> elements.get(x).size() == 1)
            .findFirst();
}
```

You might call it like this:

```
Integer[] vals = {1,2,3,1,2,4};
System.out.println(getUnique(Arrays.asList(vals))
        .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new));
```

This code uses Java 8 streams and `Optional`. Below is another implementation of the same algorithm that doesn't use Java 8 language features; if you've never encountered streams, you may find it more understandable.

```
private static <T> T getUnique(List<T> arr) {
    Map<T, Integer> numOccurrences = new HashMap<>();
    for (T item : arr) {
        numOccurrences.put(item, 1 + numOccurrences.getOrDefault(item, 0));
    }

    for (T item : arr) {
        if (numOccurrences.get(item) == 1) {
            return item;
        }
    }

    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```